# Is there anything I can do have a better utilization of CPU cores?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm running a single server process with 200 threads which are spread automatically across the CPUs in the following manner.

[image: CPU Utilization]

[image][image]

Is there anything I can do to hint the OS to spread them across the CPUs of the other node? Node 1's 16 CPUs seem to be kind of left aside.

Comment: It's probably intentional. Hopping around nodes is bad for performance due to the memory latency.

Comment: You have 16 cores on the machine. It seems to me that, for some reason, the OS can't use a core to run 2 threads in parallel, to enable Hyper-Threading. What are the threads doing?

Comment: Each thread represents a connected TCP/IP device. Most of the time they are sitting there doing nothing: sleeping 5 ms, checking if there has been any activity on its socket (0 ms) and getting back to sleep for the next 5 ms if not. That's the basic processing loop for all of the 200 threads. Best case scenario (performance wise) would be having no activity on any device. Worst case, all 200 threads processing a command.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the way to force the spread is by setting the thread affinity for the process. I'm not saying that this is the optimum scenario, or that it's better than the previous setup, but at least I managed to have the process run its threads in all the available cores. This will probably have a penalty for having threads running on nodes that have access to different memory locations, but I've the feeling that it will be smaller than having 16 cores just sitting idle. I will have to measure this, but at least I managed to move a step forward in what I wanted to achieve.

Usage by NUMA node after setting process affinity to use all cores of all nodes:

[image: Usage by NUMA nodes]

Usage by logical cores after changing same setting:

[image: Usage by logical cores]